# jquery to get value from parent list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, custom-list, lookup-column

I have a list that uses a LookupField.
I am trying to display the ParentID when I add a new item to this list.
Here is my jquery code:

```
<script src="/sites/SWR000744/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var lookupFieldDisplayName = "PIR2SIR";
        //get “ParentID” from Query String
        var vals = new Object();
        var qs = location.search.substring(1, location.search.length);
        var args = qs.split("&");
        for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            var nameVal = args[i].split("=");
            var temp = unescape(nameVal[1]).split('+');
            nameVal[1] = temp.join(' ');
            vals[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
        }
        var parentID = vals["ParentID"];
        //You should customize the first parameter to match
        //the display name of the Lookup field on your child list
        setLookup(lookupFieldDisplayName, parentID);
    });

    function setLookup(fieldTitle, lookupVal) {
        //Set default value for lookups with less that 20 items
        if ($("select[title='" + fieldTitle + "']").html() !== null) {
            $("select[title='" + fieldTitle + "']").val(lookupVal);
        } else {
            //get the hiddent input using the “optHid” attribute of displayed Input
            hiddenInput = $("input[title='" + fieldTitle + "']").attr("optHid");
            //set value in the hidden input
            $("input[id='" + hiddenInput + "']").attr("value", lookupVal)
            //get the string of choices from the input element so we can set displayed value
            choices = $("input[title='" + fieldTitle + "']").attr("choices");
            //turn choices string into an array so we can iterate through it
            choiceArray = choices.split("|");
            //improve performance by iterating over every other entry
            for (index = 1; index < choiceArray.length; index = index + 2) {
                if (choiceArray[index] == lookupVal) {
                    //set the displayed input which is the PREVIOUS entry in array
                    $("input[title='" + fieldTitle + "']").val(choiceArray[index - 1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I run the code the ParentID = empty. Also qs = empty
What am I doing wrong?

Marco

Comment: SharePoint has a built-in function named GetUrlKeyValue to get a query string paramater value. Using it instead of the code above may answer part of your question.  http://me-and-my-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2016/06/sharepoint-javascript-get-parameter.html

Comment: You mean using that like this:
    var parentID = GetUrlKeyValue('ParentID')